# Python: converting a nested list into a dictionary using as key an integer and a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I need help with my code.

I have a nested list made like this:

```
numbers = [[4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2], [2, 7, 3, 2, 7, 4], [1, 7, 4, 3, 3, 2]]
```

I also have a list of string :

```
F = ["M", "O", "R", "V", "C", "P"]
```

I want to convert the list frequency in a dictionary.
My code is this:

```
numb = dict(((i,f), numbers[i][f]) for i in range(len(numbers)) for f in range(len(numbers[0])))
```

This is the result:

```
{(0, 1): 1, (1, 2): 3, (2, 4): 3, (0, 0): 4, (2, 0): 1, (2, 2): 4, (1, 4): 7, (1, 1): 7, (1, 5): 4, (1, 3): 2, (0, 5): 2, (2, 1): 7, (2, 5): 2, (0, 4): 3, (1, 0): 2, (2, 3): 3, (0, 3): 2, (0, 2): 1}
```

The problem is that I want to utilize strings of list F as f in the key of my dictionary. I want to have:

```
{(0, "O"): 1, (1, "R"): 3, (2, "V"): 3, (0, "M"): 4, ... (0, "O"): 1}
```

I tried to change my code like this:

```
numb = dict(((i,f), numbers[i][f]) for i in range(len(numbers)) for f in F)
```

but I get in return a `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Is there a way I can fix that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm guessing a stray parenthesis. Look carefully at the error message, it will show you _where_ the syntax error is discovered (but not where the real error is).

Comment: You have too many close parantheses `)` in your last code snippet

Comment: @KindStranger thank you. I have correct the parentheses but now I obtained another type of error

Comment: f is str. you have to use:

    numb = dict(((i,f), numbers[i][F.index(f)]) for i in range(len(numbers)) for f in F)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can this be what you were looking for:

```
numb = {(i,f): numbers[i][e] for i in range(len(numbers)) for e, f in enumerate(F)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here, the first one is that you have used too many parenthesis when you have substitute the string list (two extra ones), so the end of your statement should be:

```
for f in F)
```

If you do that you will see that you don´t have a Syntax problem anymore, but you will see that you still have a problem with your indexes, because you are trying to use a string as an index. One way around this is to use the index method to return the position of the letter you are using from 'F'

With both corrections should be:

```
 numb = dict(((i,f), numbers[i][F.index(f)]) for i in range(len(numbers)) for f in F)
```

Comment: I edited the question, but thank you for the answer and explanation!